# How can we record Twilio outboud call initiating from browser to phone?

Tags: javascript, php, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am using javascript client by Twilio to make calls to any number.
But I am not able to find any solution for this.

How do we record an outbound call from browser to a phone, any server-side or client-side solution for this?

I was able to place call successfully using quickstart.js file
using below code

```
document.getElementById('button-call').onclick = function () {

    try {

        if (document.getElementById('CallTo').value != '') {
            var params = {
                To: "+" + document.getElementById('CallTo').value,
                record: 'record-from-ringing-dual'
            };         
            log('Calling ' + params.To + '...');
            console.log('Calling ' + params.To + '...');
            if (device) {
                var outgoingConnection = device.connect(params);
                outgoingConnection.on('ringing', function () {
                    log('Ringing...');
                    document.getElementById('hdnCallIDs').value = outgoingConnection.parameters.CallSid;
                    log(document.getElementById('hdnCallIDs').value);
                });
            }
        } else {
            log('Enter Dialing number...');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        log(err.message);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will put the TwiML, for the `Dial Verb`, to Record the calls returned by the Voice URL of your [TwiML Application](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180928-How-Do-I-Create-a-TwiML-App-). You instruct the Twilio clients to use a specific TwiML Application SID when creating their access tokens.

[record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#record)